# How to enable Volume & LoadBalancer on homemade Kubernetes cluster on top of GCE.

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I created a Kubernetes cluster on top of GCE VMs (a bit like kubernetes-the-hard-way) and now I'm facing lack of documentation to understand two point :

How can I integrate Google compute disks to be created when I create a PersistentVolumeClaim ?

How can I integrate Google LoadBalancer to create externalLB when I ask a Service type: Loadbalancer ?

Thanks a lot for that.

Comment: You chose a really hard way. You will need to write Kubernetes plugins that perform necessary operations like mouning persistent volumes or issuing LoadBalancer API calls to reconfigure your traffic routing. All of this is already implemented (and maintained) in Google Kubernetes Engine. What are the reasons you want to do it manually?

Comment: Thanks , I understand now the value of GKE :p 

I just like to do it complicated  ^^